# how to get the suds data in the bracket in python

Tags: parsing, suds

all,

Anyone knows how to get the type info like "ATemplateVariable" and "BTemplateVariable" in a suds object like below in python:

```
variables[] = 
            (ATemplateVariable){
               label = "labela"
               uniqueName = "namea"
               isRequired = True
               defaultValue = 300
            },
            (BTemplateVariable){
               label = "labelb"
               uniqueName = "nameb"
               isRequired = True
               defaultValue = 250
            },
            ...
```

I get the rest of the data like parsing a dict in python:

```
for var in variables:
    label = var['label']
    name = var['uniqueName']
    ...
```

But have no idea how to get the value like "ATemplateVariable" in each object.

Thanks very much

Zhihong